# Vote to close on topics we are not familiar with?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Is it fair to vote to close on topics we are not familiar with?

Example:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449180/should-i-use-silverlight-or-windows-phone-runtime-for-my-apps) tagged as `silverlight` `windows-phone-8`, I don't know much about.
Still from how the question is formulated, I can vote to close?

Above example might be a simple one, in general if we are not "pros" on topic, should we still consider to vote to close based on how the question is being asked?

**EDIT:**
Created tag specific search for flagged posts, so we can concentrate on topics we know.
[SEDE-Vote to close posts with certain tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204578/vote-to-close-posts-with-certain-tags)

Comment: vote to close only when you are confident about it.

Comment: I personally thought that while it does include some specific questions (like the differences), they are mainly opinion based or the answers would be way too broad. 

I feel that the question requires more details about the type of app, requirements, expected results, etc. But of course this is only my opinion. Even though I am one for the people who voted to close, I do not have much experience with silverlight.

Comment: An SEDE query is going to have fairly limited value here simply because the data is pretty out of data, at least for the purposes of reviewing in this manor.  You really want pretty darn up to date information when looking for questions to close.

Comment: What is the alternative to find posts that have certain tags that need closing?

Comment: I present you [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24343387/464709). From its content, it is not even possible to *determine* whether one is familiar with the topic at hand or not. And of course, the question still had to be closed (and was).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip

Comment: @zx8754 Use the close vote queue, or just look at the tag list for a given question, use search, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on the question and what option you want to use when voting.

There are some questions you can clearly see have insufficient information to answer. Even if you aren't familiar with the area you *should* be able to work out what the question is about.

However, if a question is asking for a lot of information you might not be able to close it as "too broad" as you won't know that.

In this case it's fairly clear that the question is asking for an opinion on whether to use Silverlight or not so the decision to close is fairly clear.

Without domain knowledge it's going to be difficult to cast the *first* close as duplicate vote, but (again if the question's clear enough) you might be able to tell if the question suggested by others is a duplicate.

Comment: I can rarely be sure a question is a duplicate if I don't have subject knowledge. There might be something about the new question that would make it different to an expert in its topic.